# Multiple URL parameters and rails/backbone.js

Tags: javascript, model-view-controller, url-routing, backbone.js

I have just begun to port a layered single page js app onto backbone.js and was trying to understand how to handle composite url parameters with routes and spalts in backbone.js. The backend has rails and sends JSON.

There are various entities (models) like filters, dimensions, features, questions which can be passed via request parameters.

URL 1
/display/#widget?id=42&fon=1,2,4&foff=6,9,19&q=1a2bc3abc4d

URL 2
/display/#widget?id=42&compare=345,567,90&fon=1,2,4&foff=6,9,19&q=1a2bc3abc4d

How to i structure these non-restful urls, keep the same functionality and allow bookmarkability.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Backbone's router, for the purpose of invoking views, cares only about the hash portion of `window.location`.  However, it does keep track of the search portion for the purpose of maintaining the browser history.

Therefore, the decision about bookmarkability is your responsibility: the hash will invoke a specific route, and what views that route hides or shows is up to you.  How those views parse the search string and react is also up to you.

I can see what you want to do: change a model through the search function, then render it.  It's a bit of a two-step trigger:   hash-change -> model-sync -> show-view.  Structuring that sounds like it'll be fun.  But Backbone is capable.

Comment: Thanks Elf. Can you point me to some blog post or something where this has been done before? Looking for some code snippets..